# How to reset the app icons? - They get substituted by a default icon

Tags: launcher, app-icons

Sometimes, the app icons just "switch" to an android icon:

[image: IMG:]

For example in this screenshot, the Dropbox (center row in the left) icon is an android icon. This happens to me from time to time with many different applications.

The bad icon works properly: It still opens the application normally.

If I grab the dropbox from the all-apps folder and drag-and-drop a new shortcut, it displays correctly:

[image: IMG:]

If I remove the bad icon, and leave only the correct icon it seems all normal:

[image: IMG:]

## Questions

1. Why this happens and how can I prevent it happening in the future?
2. Is there any way to "reset" all the bad icons in one shot?

Comment: Please provide more information about your phone, android version etc

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem of your launcher application.

Try clearing your launcher app's cache.

Comment: How can I know what application in the list of applications is my launcher? I've not installed any launcher different from what the default was and I don't know it's name...

Comment: Go to your device's system settings->Apps. Click on the small gear icon on the title bar->Default home app. There you can find the name and icon of your launcher application.

Comment: Under "Applications", I don't have that gear-menu and I don't have any "Default home app" option. I just see the list of the installed applications but I don't have any "Default home app" option there.

Comment: You can search about your phone's model in Google search engine and you can find where to get the 'Default Home App'.